# How did Sherlock fake his death?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

To be honest, I am quite bit confused about the **"faked death"** scene of Sherlock himself in the BBC series *Sherlock*.

The beginning of Season 3, Episode 1 shows that he escaped with the help of the rope/cord attached to the back of his coat and he seemingly broke into the nearby building and then left from there.

However when Anderson confronts him later, he actually tells another story of him jumping on an inflatable sofa (or something like that) and escaping the site. All the while John is hypnotised.

So I was looking for an answer that would help clear my dilemma.